# i need to add my customized icon to Material-ui radio button

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

But I cannot get it to work. It does not toggle when I click on it as it renders both checkedIcon and unCheckedIcon state. 
I looked at one of the source code..

```
var ActionFavoriteBorder = function ActionFavoriteBorder(props) {                                                             
return _react2.default.createElement(                        
_SvgIcon2.default,                                         
props,                                                     
_react2.default.createElement('path', { d: 'M16.5 3c-1.74 0-3.41.81-4.5    2.09C10.91 3.81 9.24 3 7.5 3 4.42 3 2 5.42 2 8.5c>
);                                                           
};
```

and looks like it needs to be converted first?!
Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the following code to render a customized radio button when it is in clicked state.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const PlatformIcon = (props) => {
let platform = props.platform, 
    color = props.color;
if (platform == "all"){
    platform = "ios_android";
}
//var imgPath = "/static/img/banner_toggle_" + platform + "_" + color + ".png";
var imgPath = "/static/img/ic_android_black_24px.svg"

return <img src={imgPath} />
}

export default PlatformIcon;
```

Thanks for your help in advance~